# how to select value and count in spring jpa?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

i have table named gifts that contains field company_value_id and i want to make select for all `company_value_id,count(company_value_id)` so that the result will be list of object and each object will contain `company_value_id,count(company_value_id)`

i am using spring jpa with annotations as follows:

```
public interface GiftsRepository extends JpaRepository<Gifts, String> {

    @Query("from Gifts g where g.companyGuid = :companyGuid")
    List<Gifts> getGiftsByCompany(@Param("companyGuid") String companyGuid);

}
```

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to accomplish it as follows:

```
@Query("select g.value.id,cr.value.name,count(g.value.id) from Gift g where g.user.id=:userId group by g.value")
    List<Object[]> getUserGifts(
            @Param("userId") String userId);
```

and in the service layer i extract the values as follows:

```
List<Object[]> results = giftsRepository
                .getUserGifts(userId);
for (Object[] result : results) {
            String id = (String) result[0];
            String name = (String) result[1];
            int count = ((Number) result[2]).intValue();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need add a parameter to your function,just like this:

```
@Query("from Gifts g where g.companyGuid = :companyGuid")
    List<Gifts> getGiftsByCompany(@Param("companyGuid") String companyGuid,Pageable pageable);
```

and the pageabel can be create like this:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageIndex, pageSize, Direction.ASC, sortColumn);
```